# Get parent Dom from child html page element

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am developing webaddin in outlook, I want to add action Icon on mail itself like Reply and Reply all in Reading pane . I have added my command button in context menu of reading pane which is in separate html page , but I want to access the dom object of reading pane from my html element button so that I can add icon in that dom object .

Is there any way to access caller DOM ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouYfF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyH0f.png)

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+outlook-addin+access+dom+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output

Comment: A screenshot where exactly you would like to place your icon can help to get the definitive answer.

Comment: sure , I have attached the screenshot :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouYfF.png

Comment: Outlook web add-ins don't provide anything for that.

Answer (score 0):

The area you pointed cannot be customized with web add-ins. There is no trivial way for adding controls there. You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.

Outlook web add-ins work under the context of currently selected items. So, any item must be selected to activate your add-in. You can add a ribbon command to your add-in, see [Add-in commands for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/add-in-commands-for-outlook?tabs=xmlmanifest) for more information. In the ribbon callback of your command you may execute any code, for example, where you may retrieve the currently selected item in Outlook (visible in the reading pane) by using the following code:

```
// Obtains the current item.
const item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
```

Then you can use the [getAsync(coercionType, options, callback)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.body?view=outlook-js-preview#outlook-office-body-getasync-member(1)) method which returns the entire current body in the format specified by `coercionType`. The following sample shows how you can get, modify and update the message body for the item:

```
const mailItem = Office.context.mailbox.item;
const base64String =
  "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";

// Get the current body of the message or appointment.
mailItem.body.getAsync(Office.CoercionType.Html, (bodyResult) => {
  if (bodyResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
    // Insert the Base64 image to the beginning of the body.
    const options = { isInline: true, asyncContext: bodyResult.value };
    mailItem.addFileAttachmentFromBase64Async(base64String, "sample.png", options, (attachResult) => {
      if (attachResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
        let body = attachResult.asyncContext;
        body = body.replace("<p class=MsoNormal>", `<p class=MsoNormal><img src="cid:sample.png">`);

        mailItem.body.setAsync(body, { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html }, (setResult) => {
          if (setResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
            console.log("Inline Base64 image added to the body.");
          } else {
            console.log(setResult.error.message);
          }
        });
      } else {
        console.log(attachResult.error.message);
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.log(bodyResult.error.message);
  }
});
```

So, following that way you may update the message body, but not to place a custom command to the drawing area.

Comment: Understand , well through ChromeExtension we can do it .I meant add icon on desire area  through Chrome extension.
I am trying to achieve by different way , just I need DOM document object of reading pane (that I am unable to get ) once I get that DOM I think I am able to add .

Comment: In web add-ins you may retrieve an HTML string which represents the  message body which is explained in my post.

Comment: yes I seen , basically that is through API , but WebAddin runs client side (browsers ) so we can do anything at UI level if able to get right DOM like what we can do through chrome extension .
Please correct me if I am wrong .

Comment: Is that a question about a chrome extension or outlook web add-in?

Comment: Its for Outlook WebAddin , both follow Javascript & browser platform.
BTW ,Thanks for your solution . Though I am looking for solution core for javascript and Outlook webaddin DOM related connectivity between internal component .

Comment: If it is for Outlook web add-in, the answer was given in my post.

Comment: Please see this image .SalesForce is able to add in Outlook WebAddin :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyH0f.png

Comment: Do you see that button on all platforms - OWA, Mac, Windows (desktop)?

Comment: All uses browser like window Desktop use Edge and web using any browser , Webaddins use browser at any platform . Similarly for MAC . Only blocker is accessing DOM object of Reading pane .

Comment: So, you don't see that button in native Outlook client applications, right?

Comment: I'd suggest posting a new question on how to inject a button in OWA from a browser extension. As I wrote, Outlook web add-ins don't provide anything for that.

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer @EugeneAstafiev . As mentioned in the answer there's getAsync api which provides selected item body. There is no add-in api which provides reading pane level dom object. 
Currently this is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our Tech Community Page-https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions. Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.